# VPN server on Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows clients, using W10 builtin VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I would like to configure some VPN server software on a Ubuntu 16.04 server such that I can connect to it from a Windows 10 laptop from home using the [Windows 10 builtin VPN client](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/20510/windows-10-connect-to-vpn).
What server software is compatible to that? I have used OpenVPN in the past, but that required installing software on the clients, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out the VPNs that Windows 10 can connect to out of the box, your best bet is probably going to be L2TP.

[Here's a guide for setting an L2TP server on Ubuntu.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/L2TPServer)